# How to assign templates to another template dynamically in sitecore?

Tags: c#, sitecore

I know how to add or create Item programmatically. My doubt is how to assign the template as below programmatically?

[image]

```
Sitecore.Data.Database masterDatabase = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
//This is master item.I want to add  some items in this template.like below programatically
Item MasterItem = masterDatabase.GetItem("/sitecore/templates/DynamicTemplates/Employees");

//This is folder which has two templates[Developers,Tester].I want to assign these two as in image programatically.
Item GetAllTemplates = masterDatabase.GetItem("/sitecore/templates/DynamicTemplates/Team");
```

Comment: I think it's bad idea to inherits template programatically.
What case you have to need such a implementation to assign Developers and Testers to MasterItem ? Why don't you just assign from Template Manager when you create Templates in the beginning ?

Comment: I agree. While I've provided an answer, I would question why this would ever be required.

Comment: #TwentyGotoTen your answers is good, but I don't think somebody need such a implementation. And you want to unassign at one moment the templates? what happening with fields from items? So  #user1381319 I think you need to consider other implementation.

Comment: sitecore climber is right, I would re-consider this need, it will get messy. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like quite a strange request and I would suggest that you reconsider because taking approach will cause you problems eventually.

Having said that, Templates are items like everything else in Sitecore so it should be possible. Once you have the `MasterItem` instantiated you should be able to add things to its `__Base template` field.

`__Base template` is a Multlist field, so the value is stored as a string of pipe separated GUIDs.

Using your variables:

```
var baseTemplates = GetAllTemplates.Children;
var baseTemplateIds = baseTemplates.Select(item => item.ID.ToString());
var fieldValue = String.Join("|",baseTemplateIds);

using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    try
    {
        MasterItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
        MasterItem["__Base template"] = fieldValue;
    }
    finally
    {   
        MasterItem.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

if you're new to editing items programatically, take a look here:

http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2009/06/ProgramaticallyItems2.aspx