# How to add templates using the ADD INSERT Option dynamically in the sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

How to assign templates to the _standard values programatically?.There is one template under Size folder.I want to add the item in the Employees _Standard values through insert option.

Steps:
1.Select the _Standard values of Employees Template.
2.add TeamSize template as follows [Click on the "Configure" >>Assign>>TeamSize
The above is manual process.I want to achieve the same using programmatically.

Just tell some sample idea alone.Rough snippet is enough.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you didn't take the advice of everyone who replied to your previous question

[How to assign templates to another template dynamically in sitecore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060665/how-to-assign-templates-to-another-template-dynamically-in-sitecore/21060968#21060968)

This really does sound like a bad idea, but if you genuinely have a good reason for this approach then the answer is very similar to that of your other question. In this case you just use the `Insert Options` field:

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Database db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master"); 

Item standardValItem = db.GetItem("/sitecore/templates/Insert Options/Employees/__Standard Values"); 
Item teamSizeTemplate = db.GetItem("/sitecore/templates/Insert Options/Size/TeamSize"); 

using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    try
    {
        standardValItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
        standardValItem[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Branches] = teamSizeTemplate.ID.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {   
        standardValItem.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sitecore.Data.Database masterDatabase = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
Item MasterItem = masterDatabase.GetItem("/sitecore/templates/Insert Options/Employees");
TemplateItem GeldTemplateName=  masterDatabase.GetTemplate("Insert Options/Size/TeamSize");
MasterItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
MasterItem["Insert Options"] = GeldTemplateName.ID.ToString();
MasterItem.Editing.EndEdit();

I tried the above logic and but still it's not loading.

Comment: I tried even that way also.still am facing the same issue.
Sitecore.Data.Database masterDatabase = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
Item MasterItem = masterDatabase.GetItem("/sitecore/templates/Insert Options/Employees");
TemplateItem GeldTemplateName=  masterDatabase.GetTemplate("Insert Options/Size/TeamSize");
foreach (Item im in MasterItem.GetChildren())
                    {
                        im.Editing.BeginEdit();
                        im["Insert Options"] = GeldTemplateName.ID.ToString();
                        im.Editing.EndEdit();
                    }

Comment: Apologies. The field should be `Sitecore.FieldIDs.Branches`, not `"Insert Options"`. I've updated my code to reflect this. I've also tested this code, and it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.I was struggling without knowing things last 2 days.your solution has helped me a lot.I am not professional sitecore developer.i have taken your advice.This is what one of our client is expecting.Thanks a lot .

Comment: For future reference, I found this information by decompiling `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.SetMasters` in `Sitecore.Kernel`

Answer (score 0):

To assign TeamSize template to Insert options of Employees you have on the new window that is opened , you have to go on Templates tree and extend Insert Option folder and choose Team Size. 
For settings dinamically Insert Options for an item you need to do :

```
yourItem.Template.StandardValues["__Master"] =yourTemplate.ID.ToString();
```

__Master is the name of the fields, you can find it here :

```
/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Insert Options/Insert Options/__Masters
```

Why do you want to change insert options dinamically ? I think you need this kind of implementation just when you have a branch website, and you want to create  from that branch other Sites. And depending on the site , on some site you need to set some Insert Options and on other no .

Please also check this [link](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/03/All-About-Insert-Options-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx) , Insert Options are explained very clear.

Comment: I want to add template programatically